# Return image view in ios 9 swift 2.1 to original position once it has been dragged but then released

Tags: swift, uiimageview, xcode7, ios9.1

I am building a simple app similar to tinder as a test. It allows users to drag a photo (image view) around to either the left or right side and a new one will load in. However when the imageview is let go of before hitting either the left or right side it is sent to the middle of the screen instead of its original starting position. I think i need to somehow store the original starting position of the image view and call on it later but am unsure of how to do it

here is my relevant code:

```
class SwipingViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var userImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var infoLabel: UILabel!

    var displayedUserId = ""


    //set image position


    func wasDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let translation = gesture.translationInView(self.view)
        let imageDrag = gesture.view!

        imageDrag.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width / 2 + translation.x, y: self.view.bounds.height / 2 + translation.y)

        let xFromCenter = imageDrag.center.x - self.view.bounds.width / 2

        let scale = min(100 / abs(xFromCenter), 1)


        var rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(xFromCenter / 200)

        var stretch = CGAffineTransformScale(rotation, scale, scale)

        imageDrag.transform = stretch



        if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

            var acceptedOrRejected = ""

            if imageDrag.center.x < 100 {

                acceptedOrRejected = "rejected"
                print("not chosen" + displayedUserId)

            } else if imageDrag.center.x > self.view.bounds.width - 100 {

                acceptedOrRejected = "accepted"
                print("Chosen")
            }

            if acceptedOrRejected != "" {

                PFUser.currentUser()?.addUniqueObjectsFromArray([displayedUserId], forKey: acceptedOrRejected)

                PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({

                    (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if succeeded {

                    } else {

                        print(error)

                    }

                })



            }

            //Resets image position after it has been let go of


            rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0)


            stretch = CGAffineTransformScale(rotation, 1, 1)

            imageDrag.transform = stretch

            imageDrag.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width / 2, y: self.view.bounds.height / 2)

            updateImage()
        }
    }
```

Here are screenshots of the issue:

**Image starting postion**

[image]

**Image Ending Position**

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help, I'm still pretty new to swift

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: And whats happening Now?

Comment: I don't believe im using auto layout, i have the screen set to iphone 5.5 inch and also the image view is constrained to the top of the screen and the horizontal middle